# Angular UI router 0.2.15, browser back/forward button not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

> I used angular v1.4.7 with UI router 0.2.15, I used $state.go and
>   ui-sref in case when from html to go to another state. I am unable to
>   go back. I checked on browser back/forward button but i haven't seen any history got pushed in. So as soon i click on back button it sends me to the empty tab.

```
'use strict';
    /**
     * Config for the router
     */
    angular.module('app').run(
        ['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
            function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;
                $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            }
        ]).config(
        ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'JQ_CONFIG', 'MODULE_CONFIG',
            function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, JQ_CONFIG, MODULE_CONFIG) {
                var layout = "tpl/app.html";
                $stateProvider.state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/app',
                    templateUrl: layout,
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            exept: ['anonymous'],
                            redirectTo: 'access.signin'
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/modal.js'])
                }).state('app.dashboard', {
                    url: '/dashboard/:tagName',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/app_dashboard_v1.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardController',
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            only: ['USER']
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/dashboard.js'])
                }).state('app.chat', {
                    url: '/chat',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/chat.html',
                    controller: 'chatCtrl',
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            only: ['USER']
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/chatCtrl.js'])
                }).state('app.accounts', {
                    url: '/accounts/:accountId/:tagName',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/group_dash.html',
                    controller: 'GroupDashController',
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            only: ['USER']
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/group_dashboard.js'])
                }).state('app.profile', {
                    url: '/profile/:accountId',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/user_profile.html',
                    data: {
                        title: 'Profile'
                    },
                    controller: 'UserProfileController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/profile.js'])
                }).state('app.feedback', {
                    url: '/feedback',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/feedback.html',
                    controller: 'feedbackController',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            only: ['USER']
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/feedback.js'])
                }).state('access', {
                    url: '/access',
                    template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>'
                }).state('access.signin', {
                    url: '/signin',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_signin.html',
                    resolve: load(['js/controllers/signin.js'])
                }).state('access.signout', {
                    url: '/signout',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_signout.html',
                    controller: "SignoutController",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    data: {
                        permissions: {
                            only: ['USER']
                        }
                    },
                    resolve: load(['js/controllers/signout.js'])
                }).state('access.signup', {
                    url: '/signup',
                    controller: "SignUpController",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_signup.html',
                    resolve: load(['toastr', 'js/controllers/signup.js'])
                }).state('access.forgotpwd', {
                    url: '/forgotpwd',
                    controller: "ForgotPassController",
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_forgotpwd.html',
                    resolve: load(['js/controllers/forgotpwd.js'])
                }).state('access.404', {
                    url: '/404',
                    templateUrl: 'tpl/page_404.html'
                });
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector) {
                    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
                    $state.go('app.dashboard');
                });

                function load(srcs, callback) {
                    return {
                        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
                            function($ocLazyLoad, $q) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                var promise = false;
                                srcs = angular.isArray(srcs) ? srcs : srcs.split(/\s+/);
                                if (!promise) {
                                    promise = deferred.promise;
                                }
                                angular.forEach(srcs, function(src) {
                                    promise = promise.then(function() {
                                        if (JQ_CONFIG[src]) {
                                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(JQ_CONFIG[src]);
                                        }
                                        angular.forEach(MODULE_CONFIG, function(module) {
                                            if (module.name == src) {
                                                name = module.name;
                                            } else {
                                                name = src;
                                            }
                                        });
                                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(name);
                                    });
                                });
                                deferred.resolve();
                                return callback ? promise.then(function() {
                                    return callback();
                                }) : promise;
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]);
```